# Behavior differences with list(map()) vs map()

Tags: python

I've come across a situation where I observed two different outcomes when testing the user defined function; `retrieve_query_tags`. When a `map` object is assigned to the `contained_tags` variable; *AssertionErrors* are raised for each test method.

Yet when the `map` object is coerced into a `list` and that list is assigned to the `contained_tags` variable; all tests pass. What is it about coercing/not coercing a map object into a list that causes this difference in behavior?

```
class TestQueryStringTags(SimpleTestCase):
    '''Verify that any tags [...] within a search query string are cleaned'''

    def setUp(self):
        self.submitted_tags = [
            "-- [  Pyth %    on]",
             "[_%!---%%%django__+___ -@& rest_framework  (^)   ]  [api]",
            "[-- django               models  ]         ",
            "$))[[django-views]]",
            " [                  ] [] >>>> [[]]  [$&))( @%)     ]"
        ]

        self.cleaned_tags = [
            ["python"], ["django-rest-framework", "api"],
            ['djangomodels'], ["django-views"], None
        ]

    def test_searched_query_tags(self):
        for i, tag_query in enumerate(self.submitted_tags):
            with self.subTest(i=i, tag_query=tag_query):
                tags = retrieve_query_tags(tag_query)
                self.assertEqual(tags, self.cleaned_tags[i])
```

```
def retrieve_query_tags(string):
    contained_tags = list(map(
        lambda match: re.sub(r"[*!#$&'\"()%*+,/:;=?@\[\]<>\s]", "", match[0])
        , re.finditer(r"(?<=\[)[^\[\]]+(?=\])", string)
    ))
    if all(not tag for tag in contained_tags):
        return None
    tag_content = list(map(
        lambda match: "-".join(
            re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z]+)", match.lower())
        ), contained_tags
    ))[:2]
    return tag_content
```

Comment: `map` produces a generator.  Once you've gone through it once, it is empty.  You cannot read anything else.  `list(map())` converts that into a list that can be iterated multiple times.

Comment: @TimRoberts to be pedantic, it is an iterator, not a generator. But yeah

Comment: Because `map` objects aren't `list` objects, why do you **expect** them to behave the same??

Answer (score 1):

Your `cleaned_tags` variable *is* a `list` object which *contains* values, but the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) object that will produce values each time its `__next__()` method is called, but can only be iterated-over one time. Coercing it into `list(map(…)` stores all those values `__next__` produced into a `list` container object (that can be traversed multiple times if required, but consumes more memory).